# Truncate a long string in python - but only after specific character

Tags: python, truncate

I use `textwrap` to split a long string into chunks, limited to 280 characters each. I don't want the split to occur at random though; it should only occur after a specific character. In my case after the `€` sign and a single line break `\n`.

This is my code:

```python
query = 'Lorem ipsum dolor\n\n Lorem ipsum 0.5€\n Lorem ipsum 0.2€\n (...)'

for item in [query]:
    # obtain length of string
    item_length = len(item)

    # check length
    if item_length <= 280:
        # do something here

    elif item_length >= 280:
        item_length_limit = item_length / 280

        # determine the number of items
        item_chunk_length = item_length / math.ceil(item_length_limit)

        # chunk the item into individual pieces
        item_chunks = textwrap.wrap(item,  math.ceil(
            item_chunk_length), break_long_words=False, replace_whitespace=False)

        # iterate over the chunks
        for x, chunk in zip(range(len(item_chunks)), item_chunks):
            if x == 0:
                print(f'{chunk} 1/{len(item_chunks)}')
            else:
                print(f'{chunk} {x+1}/{len(item_chunks)}')
```

Current output (split at 60 characters for convenience):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor\n\n Lorem ipsum 0.5€\n Lorem ipsum 1/3
dolor 0.2€\n Lorem ipsum 0.4€\n Lorem ipsum 0.4€\n Lorem 2/3
Ipsum 0.4€ 3/3
```

Desired output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor\n\n Lorem ipsum 0.5€\n 1/4
Lorem ipsum dolor 0.2€\n 2/4
Lorem ipsum 0.4€\n Lorem ipsum 0.4€\n 3/4
Lorem Ipsum 0.4€ 4/4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be the best algorithm out there, but gets the job done.

```
import re
query = "<String> I used & as a seperator"
query = f"{'a'*100}&{'b'*150}&{'c'*210}&{'d'*200}&{'e'*70}&"

chunks = re.split('&',query)

def joiner(chunks):
    i = 0
    s = ""
    newchunks = []
    while (i<len(chunks)):
        try:
            if len(chunks[i]) + len(chunks[i+1]) < 280:
                newchunks.append(chunks[i]+chunks[i+1])
                i += 1
            else:
                newchunks.append(chunks[i])
            i+= 1
        except IndexError:
            newchunks.append(chunks[i])
            i += 1
    if chunks == newchunks:##if at maximum chunking
        return chunks
    else:
        return joiner(newchunks)
```

to print the values out, just print the return value of this function

Comment: Problem: All the separator characters are removed. The code could be modified to handle this. I Didn't want to do this though as it would cloud the logic.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot!

I just added `+'\n'` here to get the line breaks back:
`newchunks.append(chunks[i]+'\n'+chunks[i+1])`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your question, but are you looking for something like that ?

```
query.split('€\n')
```

It will create a list where every entry is a snippet of your string in-between everytime you encounter the '€\n' characters.

Comment: Thanks! But the split should only occur if the whole "query" is longer than 280 characters, i.e.: if query >280 split into chunks < 281 characters - but only after €\n

Comment: @trashjazz check the `len(query)` value with an `if` statement.

Comment: Ok now I understand a bit more but it's still unclear to me what you really want to do.

Comment: I'd want the chunks to look like this:
`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n\n Lorem 0.5€\n 1/3`
`Lorem 0.2€\n Lorem 0.4€\n 2/3`
`Lorem 0.3€\n Lorem 0.1€\n 3/3`

instead of this:
`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n\n Lorem 0.5€\n Lorem 0.2 1/3`
`€\n Lorem 0.4€\n Lorem 2/3`
`0.3€\n Lorem 0.1€\n 3/3`

Comment: So you don't want to truncate after every `€\n` sign, but after every 2 of them, right ? 

Because if I follow your original question as I understand it you'd get: 
`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n\n Lorem 0.5€\n 1/5`
`Lorem 0.2€\n 2/5`
`Lorem 0.4€\n 3/5`
`Lorem 0.3€\n 4/5`
`Lorem 0.2€\n 5/5`

Comment: Not quite. :D I have a huge string ("query") and instead I want several chunks that are not bigger than 280 characters. textwrap would do the job, but it splits the string at random. I want the split to occur only after `€\n`.

Comment: Mmh then the `query.split('€\n')` should do the job because if you add it in an `if` loop (where you make sure it doesn't run unless your string is longer than 280), take a look at my edit and see if it suits you (for a reason printing the chunks 1-by-1 gives weird result but printing the whole list works)

Comment: Thanks again! I'm using `split` now with Dominic's code above.

Answer (score 0):

This is will work

```
query = r'Lorem ipsum dolor\n\n Lorem ipsum 0.5€\n Lorem ipsum 0.2€\n (...)'
#raw required
split_string = query.split(r"0.5€\n")
for i in split_string:
  print(i)
```

This splits the string into an array and then prints the result

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! `split` does the trick with Dominic's code above.